# What website that provide latitude and azimuth of any city or village such as Sofia

Tags: azimuth

What website that provide latitude and azimuth of any City or Village such as Sofia?

It would be nice to have general list for commonly used translation of latitude and longitude as well as azimuths based on city or GPS cor-ord.

Comment: azimuth of a city???

Comment: Yes, that precisely the query!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good and free database is NaturalEarth: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-populated-places/